# How can I write an emoji in XML layout file, in an escaped unicode format?

Tags: java, android, unicode

Currently, I am experimenting with emoji with various skin tone color and gender.

The following XML code has no problem during rendering.

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="‍"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

The "grinning" face emoji is having unicode U+1F600

However, based on data from

https://emojiterra.com/grinning-face/ (The "Java, JavaScript & JSON" is showing "\uD83D\uDE00")

If I were to write it using

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="\uD83D\uDE00"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

or

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="\u1F600"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

None of them really work. May I know why it is so? How can I write "‍" in an escaped unicode format?

p/s

Note, the following 2 lines of Java code works without any issue, if we run on Desktop environment.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE00");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think specifying Unicode values directly in `android:text` within the `TextView` is supported. Instead, define the Unicode values in **strings.xml**, and reference those definitions from your `TextView`. See [Special Character in Android](https://droidbyme.medium.com/special-character-in-android-c7f10a490911) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add \uD83D\uDE00 in strings.xml it work for me

```html
<string name="txt_emoji">\uD83D\uDE00</string>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_emoji" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XML, any character can be encoded using its Unicode code-point, as a so-called ["character entity reference"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-references) using a syntax like this:

```xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="&#x1F600;"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

The initial `&` character introduces the entity reference, and the trailing `;` terminates it. The `#` indicates that the reference is a *numeric* reference (as opposed to referring to an entity by name), and the `x` indicates that the number is in hexadecimal. The `1F600` is the Unicode codepoint.

NB Java and JavaScript use the `\` character as an escape mechanism but in XML, as in HTML, it has no special meaning; a `\` just signifies a `\`.